# Animated view does not save its state in ViewPager

Tags: android, animation, view, android-viewpager

I have extends `PagerAdapter` from v4 support library.
I am displaying some view in the pages and giving rotate animation to the those views.

Now I have set `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);`

Now I have given rotate animation to the view on the first page. I have save the reference of this view to my list. So when I will go to 3rd page and will come to first page again, I will take this saved view's reference and will return saved view to display on fist page.

I am facing issue is like, **view loses its animated state** after adding it to first page again. It happens on Samsung galaxy s3(android version 4.1.2) . But this code is working properly on other android devices like motorola DroidX(android version 2.3.x) , HTC (android version 2.3.x)  , samsung galaxy ACE(android version 2.2.x) .

I am not getting where is the issue. If I change the offScreenPageLimit then its working on all device.

Would you please suggest me any solution for this issue ?